# Data from OSM (overpy) to geodataframe with polygons

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, overpass-api

I try to put OSM data (some polygons) to geodataframe.
Export from OSM contains LineString. But in the end i need to converte all data into geodataframe in this format:

0 -> name_from_tag_first_area -> polygon (or multipolygon) type with coordinates

1 -> name_from_tag_second_area -> polygon (or multipolygon) type with coordinates

And then i will use this GeoDataFrame to visualize this polygons.

```
import overpy
import requests
import json
import geopandas as gpd

from shapely.geometry import shape

url = "https://maps.mail.ru/osm/tools/overpass/api/interpreter"
query = """[out:json];
area['boundary' = 'administrative']['name' = 'Москва'] -> .MSK;
(
relation(area.MSK)['admin_level' = 8]['boundary' = 'administrative']['name'='Бескудниковский район'];
relation(area.MSK)['admin_level' = 8]['boundary' = 'administrative']['name'='район Восточное Дегунино'];
);
convert item ::=::,::geom=geom(),_osm_type=type();
out geom;"""
response = requests.get(url, params={'data': query})
data = response.json()

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data['elements'])
```

[image: wrong result]

In my dataframe not a polygon - only `GeometryCollection` with `LineString`. Please could you explain how I can do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from an additional import I will keep the beginning of your script as the same.

```
import overpy
import requests
import json
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import shape, MultiPolygon
from shapely.ops import polygonize

url = "https://maps.mail.ru/osm/tools/overpass/api/interpreter"
query = """[out:json];
area['boundary' = 'administrative']['name' = 'Москва'] -> .MSK;
(
relation(area.MSK)['admin_level' = 8]['boundary' = 'administrative']['name'='Бескудниковский район'];
relation(area.MSK)['admin_level' = 8]['boundary' = 'administrative']['name'='район Восточное Дегунино'];
);
convert item ::=::,::geom=geom(),_osm_type=type();
out geom;"""
response = requests.get(url, params={'data': query})
data = response.json()
```

Your GeoDataFrame contains GeoJSON Geometries. In the first step the geometries have to be converted to shapely geometries with the `shape` function. After that we convert the GeometryCollections to Polygons with the
`polygonize` function.

```
results_dict = [{
    'id': element['id'],
    'name': element['tags']['name'],
    'geometry': MultiPolygon(polygonize(shape(element['geometry']))),
} for element in data['elements']]
```

Now you can convert your `results_dict` into a GeoDataFrame. Note that a boundary could be multiple Polygons. Maybe you want each Polygon to has it's own row. For this you can use the `explode` function.

```
results_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(results_dict)
# or
results_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(results_dict).exlode()
```

Comment: Thanks, it's works!
But when I try to do it with a polygon that has holes - i get the wrond result. How to fix it?

Comment: @and_dlg hmm. I'm not sure if there is a tool that detects holes in polygons out of the box. But it shouldn't be hard to implement this logic yourself. With shapely you can detect if a polygon is part of another polygon (=hole). If that's the case you create a new polygon with holes.

Comment: Should I do it via explode() or another way?
When i use explode() for this multipolygon i see 3 polygon. And one of them is result with holes from overpass api and another 2 polygon - holes polygon.